# I cannot find gRPC after I installed grpc using vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, grpc, vcpkg

[image]

You can i installed grpc successfully, the hint shows:

```
# this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

but when i add it to CMakeLists.txt, error occurs:
[image]

i dont know how to fix it...

i want to know the steps to fix this problem...

Comment: Did you [integrate vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html) as the documentation states?